# Excel formula how to concatenate string for external reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say I have the following formula in a cell that reads the value of a cell from another work book

```
='c:\temp\[external book.xlsx]SheetX'!$E$4
```

and I want the value of `c:\temp\[external book.xlsx]SheetX` to come from another cell in this sheet. How would I rewrite this formula to concatenate this value and `"!$E$4"`

Lets say the cell `A1` contains `c:\temp\[external book.xlsx]SheetX`

Comment: Is it possible to write this as an Excel function that can be called from a cell where the cell formula for A1=INDIRECT_2(A2) and the value of A2='c:\temp\[external book.xlsx]SheetX'!$E$4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** As the below won't work on a closed workbook, here is a clunky proof-of-concept of how you could do it with VBA (I imagine there are better ways of doing this):

```vb
Sub ClosedWorkbook()

Dim currSht As Worksheet
Dim targetWbk As Workbook
Dim Path As String

' Turn off updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Set a reference to the current sheet
Set currSht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

' Get the value in the formula cell (A1 here, could be ActiveCell if in a loop, etc.)
PathSheet = currSht.Range("A1").Value

' Split out the path - this is very clunky, more of a proof (?) of concept
' This is depends on the path being as you mentioned, and the IF block is to 
' check if the apostrophe is present in the cell (since it is the escape character,
' it is usually skipped)
If Left(PathSheet, 1) = "'" Then
  Path = Replace(Mid(PathSheet, 2, InStr(PathSheet, "]") - 2), "[", "")
  Sheet = Mid(PathSheet, InStr(PathSheet, "]"))
  Sheet = Left(Sheet, Len(Sheet) - 2)
Else
  Path = Replace(Mid(PathSheet, 1, InStr(PathSheet, "]") - 1), "[", "")
  Sheet = Mid(PathSheet, InStr(PathSheet, "]") + 1)
  Sheet = Left(Sheet, Len(Sheet) - 2)
End If

' Open the target workbook
Set targetWbk = Workbooks.Open(Path)

' Grab the value from E4 and drop it in a cell (D1 here, could be ActiveCell, etc.)
MyValue = targetWbk.Sheets(Sheet).Range("E4").Value
currSht.Range("D5").Value = MyValue

' Close the target
targetWbk.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**OLD WAY** (doesn't work on closed workbooks)

I believe this captures what you're looking for. In this example, cell `A1` had my sheet path:

```
'C:\temp\[externalworkbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!
```

In cell B1 I have the formula:

```
=INDIRECT(A1 & "$E$4")
```

Which concatenates the sheet value with `$E$4` in order to generate the full path, which is then turned into a value by `INDIRECT`. One thing to note: the apostrophe is an escape character, so depending on your data, you may have to account for it specially in your formula:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "$E$4")
```

If you're using Excel 2007 or above, you could wrap it in an `IFERROR` formula to take out the guesswork:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(A1 & "$E$4"),INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "$E$4"))
```

Comment: @PreetSangha Yeah, meant to drop that in there. I'll see if I can think of something if it is closed.

Comment: Thanks, but Indirect doesn't work if the external is workbook  (a) closed or (b) open in a different instance of Excel unforturnetly

Comment: @PreetSangha Is VBA an option? Also, I'll add the `excel` tag to this post - there are people far better than I who will probably have much better ideas.

Comment: Sure if it's the only way then I'm happy

Comment: @PreetSangha Alright, dropping a sample in there now. Definitely not proud of it - more of a proof of concept. Relies on opening/closing the target book, so hopefully that fits your use case. Happy to help flesh it out / make more dynamic if it fits your cause.