# Copying data without opening workbook using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm intending to copy data from one workbook to another through a macro. However, I'm using an Add-In my company has created, which prohibits more than one workbook to be open at once.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
CurrentYear = Year(Date)
CurrentMonth = Month(Date)
StartDate = DateAdd("m", MonthOffset, Date)
MonthNo = Month(StartDate)
YearNo = Year(StartDate)

path2 = IIf(MonthNo >= 10, Dir("C:\path\filename " & YearNo & "-" & MonthNo & ".xlsx"), Dir("C:\path\filename " & YearNo & "-0" & MonthNo & ".xlsx"))
p2file = "C:\path"

Varrr = IIf(MonthNo >= 10, p2file & path2 & "[filename.xlsx " & YearNo & "-" & MonthNo & ".xlsx]Sheetname!", p2file & path2 & "[filename.xlsx " & YearNo & "-" & MonthNo & ".xlsx]Sheetname!") 
i = 0
Do While Len(path2) > 0
    Varrrcell = Cells(3,4+i).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)        
    Varrr = Varrr & Varrrcell  
    currentWb.Sheets("Blad1").Cells(27, 2 + i + 12 * (YearNo Mod 2015)).Formula= "=Varrr"


    i = IIf(i > 12, 1, i + 1)  
    YearNo = IIf(i > 12, YearNo + 1, YearNo)    
    path2 = IIf(i >= 10, Dir("C:\path\filename " & YearNo & "-" & i & ".xlsx"), Dir("C:\path\filename" & YearNo & "-0" & i & ".xlsx"))
    Varrr = IIf(i >= 10, p2file & path2 & "[filename.xlsx " & YearNo & "-" & MonthNo & ".xlsx]Sheetname!", p2file & path2 & "[filename.xlsx " & YearNo & "-" & MonthNo & ".xlsx]Sheetname!") 
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

EDIT: I've recoded my work to reference to the workbook directly using formula. This solution actually returns the correct path, file and cell I want to copy so that works as intended. However, it returns "Varrr" in each cell. How can I make it return the value instead of the variable name?

EDIT2: I've also contatenated "='" before path2 & p2file & ".." when creating and updating Varrr, and simply saying that

```
 currentWb.Sheets("Blad1").Cells(27, 2 + i + 12 * (YearNo Mod 2015)).Formula= Varrr
```

but this causes error 1004

EDIT3: I've also added a "closing" ' before the name of the sheet. It did not help.

EDIT4: I've also tried to omit the equal signs, and contenated Varrr = Varrr & Varrcell

and subsequentially put:

```
  currentWb.Sheets("Blad1").Cells(27, 2 + i + 12 * (YearNo Mod 2015)).Formula = "=" & varrr
```

but it gives code 1004 in the same code snippet. "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

EDIT 5:
Trying to incorporate ExecuteExcel4Macro I've tried the following solution, where Dim ReturnedValue as String:

```
    Varrr = "'" & p2file & "[filename.xlsx " & YearNo & "-" & MonthNo & ".xlsx]Sheetname!'"
    ReturnedValue = Varrr & Range("D3").Adress(True,True,-4150)
    MsgBox ExecuteExcel4Macro(ReturnedValue)
```

where the MsgBox gives function error 1004. Here I have trimmed it down a bit to omit the "IIf" statement and the Do loop as I Believe these are redundant in the context.

Comment: Calling `Workbooks.Open` clearly opens the workbook (as the name makes very clear). You can't copy data from a workbook without opening it, any more than you can read page 100 in a book without opening it first.

Comment: It is possible to get data (not copy, per se) from a closed workbook using ADO, or using `ExecuteExcel4Macro`, or just using formulas that you then convert to values if necessary. Which is the best will depend on your circumstances.

Comment: you could write a vbs to open each workbook, one at a time storing information into and out of variables as you go. This would be fiddly but I would expect it to be one way to go.

Comment: @Rory Thanks for those examples. Been googling ADO, and it seems promising!

Comment: @The_Barman Thanks for your reply! I'm taking that into consideration as well. Always nice to find different approaches

Comment: @Rory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059343/excel-formula-how-to-concatenate-string-for-external-reference asks the same thing as I do basically, and I wonder if you know if there is in fact a way to contanate a string using a simple "=pathtofile" formula, to account for what I achieve in my code using Dir? The accepted answer in that link also depends on opening up the other workbook

Comment: Start a new instance of excel and open the source file in that instance.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for your reply. Is there no way of avoiding to open up any additional files, through the use of formula? From what I've gathered, it should be possible to do an approach which I've started to create, by simply using "='pathtofile\[filename.xlsx]'!Cell". If I've understood it correctly, opening up a source file will cause my program to shut down due to the add-ins. I cannot make an additional Excel file, import the data I want through the Company add-in, and subsequently importing these data into Another workbook, as the Add-in Workbook must be open in order to display data.

Comment: Does your add-in really know what's going on in all open instances of Excel?  Can you test that?  And why is the add-in doing that anyway?

Comment: Your formula string needs an apostrophe after the = sign and another immediately after the sheet name.

Comment: @TimWilliams I can test that. I have no clue actually. It is just a company add-in for deducting internal data.

Comment: @Rory Thanks for another reply. I may have been vague, but "EDIT3" is exactly that. 

I've been trying to google ExecuteExcel4Macro, and I've seen a tutorial for it. I've tried to set up my varrr to become be 'pathtofile\[filename.xlsx]Sheetname!' and then I've used 

ReturnedValue = varrr & Range("D3").Address(True,True,-4150) 
and MsgBox ExecuteExcel4Macro(ReturnedValue), but this gave errors "Error in Formula 1004". Is there something I've misunderstood with ExecuteExcel4Macro?

Comment: Where Dim returnedValue as string

Comment: For both operations, your formula string needs to be of the form: `='C:\path to file\[workbook name]Sheet name'!cell_address`. Note both apostrophes. For `ExecuteExcel4Macro` the range reference should be in R1C1 format.

Comment: @Rory I've added both '. From my previous comment I've added .Adress, which I have adjusted to become R1C1 format, but it does not work.

Comment: What **exactly** is in your formula string when you try it?

Comment: @Rory Thanks for being so involved in this issue, it is very much appreciated. I have edited my original post now.